# How to implement a Silverlight Control for time table(scheduler)

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

My company is going to development drag and drop feature in Silverlight. We are very new to Silverlight and just learnt SL for a week ago. But I believe the feature that my company wants can be done in Silverlight. The control about is about the time table in which the resource will be shifted around.

Here is the feature detail. We have one list box on left (resource list) and one table on the right. What we want to do is drag an item from the list onto the table then may have some data manipulation on table. I think it’s simple and but for me I don’t know how to create the table which is I think there is no built in control like this. Please take a look my screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCaVX.jpg

My questions are:

- How can we approach to achieve this
  feature?
- What is the best way to implement
  this control?
- How we can handle the event such as
  drop, reload, bind and so on?
- How can we select and drag cell on
  table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Silverlight can do that. It has drag-drop and rich support for creating custom user controls.

The Telerik RadControls for Silverlight have a control that does some of what you need. They also make source available.

You might want to research all the available third party controls first to save development cost.

There are too many questions in your question to answer. Best do your research and then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik control is called RadScheduleView and can be seen here: http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ScheduleView/FirstLook. It has nice performance and a lot of features.

Answer (score 0):

We are also using Telerik RadScheduleView .It is simple and lot of demos for you to start.